# Jquery add attributes in an element using Skrollr

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I have this code working when I put to my HTML file.

```
<div id="airballoon-wrapper"
    data-0="top:45px; left:50%;"
    data-992="top:375px; left:37%;"
    data-2400="top:160px; left:40%;"
    data-4920="top:210px; left:78%;">

    <div id="airballoon">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/air-balloon.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I used Jquery to add attributes, it doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="airballoon-wrapper">
    <div id="airballoon">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/air-balloon.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#airballoon-wrapper").attr({
     "data-0": "top:45px; left:50%;",
     "data-992": "top:375px; left:37%;",
     "data-2400": "top:160px; left:40%;",
     "data-4920": "top:210px; left:78%;"
});
```

Any solution for this stuff?

Comment: HTML 5 only supports data attribute

Comment: Call `skrollr.init` or `refresh` **after** changing the attributes

Comment: ^ It works! I Love you! It helped a lot! No homo. :D